# rendering postscript with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, postscript

Is it possible to output postscript in Matplotlib? For example this little square:

```
newpath
0 0 moveto
1 0 lineto
1 1 lineto
0 1 lineto
0 0 lineto
stroke
```

I want to load this code in Matplotlip and render it on IPython (just an example).

Comment: If you just want to show PostScript figures in IPython, you could consider PostCanvas: http://www.feiri.de/pcan/

Answer (score 2):

Matplotlib has a `Path` interface which works very similar:
http://matplotlib.org/users/path_tutorial.html

But you will have to load the text and do some munging yourself. But consider this example:

```
import matplotlib.path as mpath
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Start with the text, as a string, from your example.

```
instr = """newpath
0 0 moveto
1 0 lineto
1 1 lineto
0 1 lineto
0 0 lineto
stroke"""
```

Split on the line-breaks, and remove the first and last line. Perhaps the last should be used for final formatting?

```
verts = instr.split('\n')[1:-1]
verts
```

Convert each line to a coordinate and a code.

```
code_lookup = {'moveto': mpath.Path.MOVETO,
               'lineto': mpath.Path.LINETO}

coords = [(i.split(' ')[0], i.split(' ')[1]) for i in verts]
codes = [code_lookup[i.split(' ')[2]] for i in verts]

# set the last code to close the polygon
codes[-1] = mpath.Path.CLOSEPOLY
```

Construct the polygon.

```
mypath = mpath.Path(coords, codes)
mypatch = patches.PathPatch(mypath, facecolor='orange', lw=2)
```

Plot the result.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'aspect': 1.0, 
                                   'xlim': [-1,2], 
                                   'ylim': [-1,2]})


ax.add_patch(mypatch)
```

[image]

Comment: this is all great but what I ask is a general way of converting all postscript into a plot. thanks for pointing the path api solution though, didn't knew it very well.

Comment: This really is the core of postscript. If you check this [old thread of mine](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.lang.postscript/wrkPdGdw8cE/discussion), the heart of the Warnock/Wyatt stencil/paint image model is the single function `DisplayConvexPolygon` which performs the transformation->clipping->filling steps. Everything else is built on top of this. (Ignoring issues of syntax)